# Screen not displaying the horizontal layout upon rotation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-orientation

I am an Android newbie who is learning how to develop Android applications. I don't see a landscape layout being displayed. The images just show the portrait layout. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

[Recycler View in Portrait Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIQ9L.png)

[View Pager in Portrait Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rscs.png)

When I rotate the screen, then I don't see any change in screen in landscape mode, the screens are not rotated.

Here are same screens in landscape mode.

[Recycler View in landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDURl.png)

[View Pager in landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zpuw.png)

Phone Settings
[Phone Settings # 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXePe.png)

I have a github that I am trying to create.

My layout files.

Portrait layout (portrait)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container">


</FrameLayout>
```

Landscape layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
</FrameLayout>
```

Recycler View (portrait and landscape)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/crime_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Recycle View Row (Portrait and Landscape)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/crime_title_hint"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/crime_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/crime_date"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crime_title" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="Test image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

View Pager Screen (Portrait)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/first_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/first_crime"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/last_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/last_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/last_crime"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/first_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/first_button" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/id_crime_pager"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/first_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

View Pager Screen (Landscape)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/first_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/first_crime"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_crime_pager" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/last_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/last_crime"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/first_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_crime_pager" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/id_crime_pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/first_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would appreciated.

I have a github project that I have created. I would appreciate any help that any one have

https://github.com/manoflogan/android-projects/tree/pager_assignment/02-Criminalntent

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: A couple of possibilities: 1) Your device's auto-rotate setting is disabled or 2) You've specified ```android:screenOrientation="portrait"``` for your activity in your manifest file.

Comment: As far as (2) is concerned, I confirmed that that is not the case. https://github.com/manoflogan/android-projects/blob/pager_assignment/02-Criminalntent/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml. How do I confirm the first one?

Comment: I tried your code it works perfectly as mentioned by @MichaelKrause it is the first case.Go to device settings and enable auto rotation of screen and then check, it worked for me.

Comment: @MayurGajra I have updated my phone settings. It still fails.